# How to parse the data from OBD II simulator for every 2 seconds in android

Tags: android, obd-ii, elm327

I have developed the android application to parse the data from OBD II simulator through Bluetooth for every 10 seconds.

Now I am trying to parse the data from OBD II simulator for every 2 seconds. Is it possible ?

Note : I have not mentioned explicitly not mentioned 10 seconds in my code.

Getting below log in OBD II simulator:

```
Successfully initialised obdsim, entering main loop
10.001125 seconds. 0 samples, 0 queries. 0.00 s/s, 0.00 q/s
10.001004 seconds. 0 samples, 0 queries. 0.00 s/s, 0.00 q/s
Bluetooth connected: 50:8F:4C:B0:73:06
Reset
Echo disabled
Echo disabled
Linefeed disabled
Timeout 248
New Protocol: Automatic
10.093171 seconds. 6 samples, 33 queries. 0.59 s/s, 3.27 q/s
10.242840 seconds. 8 samples, 31 queries. 0.78 s/s, 3.03 q/s
10.063721 seconds. 10 samples, 34 queries. 0.99 s/s, 3.38 q/s
10.115888 seconds. 9 samples, 35 queries. 0.89 s/s, 3.46 q/s
10.238775 seconds. 8 samples, 31 queries. 0.78 s/s, 3.03 q/s
```

Comment: There is not even sort of enough information provided in this question.  What hardware, what libraries, etc.  Can you query modules over OBD2 faster than every 2 seconds?  Definitely, many tools query modules hundreds or thousands of times per second when data logging.  I'd recommend putting a little bit more effort into your question to provide more clairity of what you need help with.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @DamonEarl. 1.Presently I am not using hardware , just receiving the data from OBD II simulator to android application. 2. In the application I am using the com.github.pires:obd-java-api:1.0-RC10 library. I am receiving the data from every 10 seconds. Now I am trying receive the data from every 2 sounds, Could you please suggest tool for this.